# Task only run once on Timer

Tags: c#

Good day, I'm beginner and trying to learn how to run my long and repeatedly running task on timer.

What I wanted to achieve is to make my method below run every 100 milliseconds. (please correct me if there's something wrong)

```
  private void Long_Running_Task()
    {
        DateTime timeticking = DateTime.Now;
        using (MySqlConnection ccon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            ccon.Open();
            MySqlCommand ccom = new MySqlCommand("Select * From table1", ccon);
            MySqlDataReader creader = ccom.ExecuteReader();
            while (creader.HasRows && creader.Read())
            {
                string etime = creader.GetString(creader.GetOrdinal("Time"));
                string etimeformat = creader.GetString(creader.GetOrdinal("TimeFormat"));
                string edate = creader.GetString(creader.GetOrdinal("Date"));
                DateTime tdate = Convert.ToDateTime(edate);
                var newedate = todatetime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                string expected_datetime_for_report = newedate + " " + etime + " " + etimeformat;
                var selecttimeticking = timeticking.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt");
                if (selecttimeticking == expected_datetime_for_report)
                {
                    using (MySqlConnection ccon2 = new MySqlConnection(connString))
                    {
                        MySqlCommand ccom2 = new MySqlCommand();
                        string completes = "Complete";
                        ccon2.Open();
                        ccom2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE table1 SET Report_Progress=@reportstatus WHERE Date=@day && Time=@time && TimeFormat=@timeformat", ccon2);
                        ccom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", newexpecteddate);
                        ccom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", expectedtime);
                        ccom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeformat", expectedtimeformat);
                        ccom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportstatus", completes);
                        ccom2.ExecuteReader();
                        ccon2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            creader.Dispose();
            ccon.Close();
        }
    }
```

when it comes to functionality of the method, it is doing what is supposed to be doing but only run once when I try this on timer.

```
    private void Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Task longrun = new Task(()=>Long_Running_Task());
      longrun.Start();
    }
```

When I put the code of my method to my timer "Time_Tick" it runs again and again with only single problem it lags when I had a lot of data to run on my selected date for example 10/07/2017 11:30 PM.

I know this is kind of big problem somehow but I'm willing to learn, be corrected and take some advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: You want this _job_ to be _scheduled_ to run every 100ms?

Comment: I set the timer to 100 ms but if its pretty dumb then I will try to change that. When I put my code inside the timer instead of using task to call it. it runs nicely somehow. thank you for replying

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer the question. It's also not even clear what the problem is. First you write _" it is doing what is supposed to be doing but only run once"_ but then you write _"it runs again and again"_. Which is it? Does it run only once? Or does it run "again and again"? Fact is, you also seem to be overly optimistic, thinking the task in question could complete in 100ms. But first, we need to understand the _question_.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and rethink this. Would it be easier to create a console app who has the sole responsibility of performing your logic.  Then setting up a scheduled job in your OS or Server to run this every x min/second?

Comment: When I said "it is doing what is supposed to be doing but only run once" I mean when I tried putting my code in timer                                                                                                            It run once. But when I put the code from the method in the timer it runs again and again "which I like" but for sometime it lags or the visual studio stopped and not responding. My sole question is how to make it happen using Task. I'll rewrite the question again and thank you so much for your replies.

Comment: What happens if you increase the time to, say 10 seconds? I wonder if the method is able to complete in 100ms since it involves not only an update but also a select *. It might be that all the update statements pile up.

Comment: Sir Peter Bons, thank you for your suggestion. I'll make sure that I'll try that one.

Comment: Please include the code that sets up the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, when I run into an issue like this, I usually tackle it by having the function not get kicked off if there's a previous instance running.  Here's a nice class to help take care of it for you:

```
public class RecurringTask
{
    private Action procedureToRunRepeatedly;
    private Timer timer;
    private Task task;

    public RecurringTask(Action procedureToRunRepeatedly, int millisecondsBetweenRuns)
    {
        this.procedureToRunRepeatedly = procedureToRunRepeatedly;
        this.timer = new Timer();
        this.timer.Tick += TickEvent;
        this.timer.Interval = millisecondsBetweenRuns;
        this.timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (task != null)
            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Running) return;
        task = new Task(procedureToRunRepeatedly);
        task.Start();
    }
}
```

Basically, all you have to do is create an instance of RecurringTask, feed in the Action that you want it to perform, and how many milliseconds you want between calls.  If the task is still running when the next 'tick' occurs, it simply exits out and waits for the next tick.

In my example case, I just did something silly like:

```
private RecurringTask myTask = new RecurringTask(DoTest, 2000);
public void DoTest()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it really helps. Unlike people before you, you tried to understand and it happens that it helped me. Thank you so much